# How to use custom painter to draw half circle

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painter

[image]

I want to draw curve like image above can anyone help me if can ?

Comment: Follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748469/flutter-how-to-draw-semicircle-half-circle    add your logics and complete it

Comment: I was saw that but i can't make my own

Comment: then i will sueggest you to create a image adobe photoshop and simple call it in image.asset :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `quadraticBezierTo` with Paint `shader`. play with `quadraticBezierTo`'s value to meet your need.

```dart
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(20, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2, size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 20)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 1.3, 0, 20);

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..shader =
          LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blue.withOpacity(.4)])
              .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[image]