# Flutter: How do I create a semicircle on top of this widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, mobile-development

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/gauges.dart';

class CreditScoreGauge extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: SfRadialGauge(
        axes: <RadialAxis>[
          RadialAxis(
            showLabels: false,
            showTicks: false,
            minimum: 300,
            maximum: 850,
            startAngle: 180,
            endAngle: 0,
            axisLineStyle: const AxisLineStyle(
              thickness: 0.12,
              cornerStyle: CornerStyle.bothCurve,
              thicknessUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              gradient: SweepGradient(colors: <Color>[
                Color(0xffa2c9e1),
                Color(0xff62769D),
                Color(0xff354F81),
                Color(0Xff1B3568),
                Color(0xff122345),
              ], stops: <double>[
                0,
                0.35,
                0.7,
                0.8,
                1.0
              ]),
            ),
            pointers: const <GaugePointer>[
              MarkerPointer(
                  value: 600,
                  markerHeight: 25,
                  markerWidth: 25,
                  markerType: MarkerType.circle,
                  enableDragging: true,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(0, 3, 168, 244),
                  borderWidth: 7,
                  elevation: 10,
                  borderColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my my widget using 'syncfusion_flutter_gauges: ^20.1.59' dependency that 
displays the following gauge:

[image]

And my desired goal is the following:

[image]

I want to add the semi circle depicted in the picture but I am having trouble with it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would find this answer helpful:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748494/14531784

It creates a semi-circle using CustomPainter widget. Now, to place it on top of of you widget (SfRadialGauge) I think you could wrap that widget and the semi-circle with Stack widget.